# Powershell Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Tags: powershell, base64

I have this script which downloads a base64 encoded text and tries to decode it.

In the meanwhile my script goes like this:

```
powershell.exe "set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted ; $WebClient = New-Object net.WebClient ; $string$WebClient.DownloadString('http://127.0.0.1:1234/b64.txt'); [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($string))"
```

The download part works very well, though, the decode part seems to give the following exception:

```
Exception calling "FromBase64String" with "1" argument(s): "Invalid length for
a Base-64 char array."
At line:1 char:222
+ set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted ; $WebClient = New-Object net.WebClient ; $s
tring = $WebClient.DownloadString('http://127.0.0.1:1234/b6464.txt'); [System.
Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String <<<< ($string
))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any clue why this is happening? Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the base64 encoding string is not a valid length: not all lengths are valid (each encoded character provides 5 bits of data, but resulting data needs to be a multiple of 8 bits.

Eg. it is missing one or two padding characters at its end.

Comment: Thanks! I mistakenly pasted the wrong base64 string :(